# Extra text in footer in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a Script . there have a footer text after

```
</body></html>
```

that means end of every page .i searching  all view file and some off others directories not find out that text . so is there any possibility File i can get this footer text. i have not enough knowledge in laravel ..

Comment: I can't understand what's tyour problem. Where are the text placed?

Comment: at the end of every page ... after closing </body></html> and i already search every file in resources folder but no luck

Comment: So you have a text appearing on every page on the web browser, but can't find it on your blade views?

Comment: yah its the main problem

Comment: What is the text?

Answer (score 0):

As you mecioned, you cant find text on your footer.
That is probably beacause you have a template for content
search line code

`section('content')`
 or maybe 
`section('footer')`
This is the section you are working on.

- Go back to your views folder
- Open app.blade.php, find yield('content') or what your looking for, there you have the code included into all views.
- or maybe you have a view fooder.blade.php the footer of all views

That is templating logic on laravel, you can search all code following the sections.

If there is no a layouts folder, look for something with related name.